# keydown event Does not work on forms but does work on Datagridview in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, event-handling, keydown

Keydown Event Does not work on form1 but does work on datagrid. However i want it to work on form1 only. If i comment the lines in datagrid Keydown Event The event in still form1 does not work. Can somebody help me? this is just a sample coding.The datagridview is dock in the form.

```
Private Sub form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If ((e.KeyCode = Keys.Z) AndAlso e.Control) Then
        MsgBox("hello")
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub DataGrid_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGrid.KeyDown
    If ((e.KeyCode = Keys.Z) AndAlso e.Control) Then
        MsgBox("hello")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `.KeyPreview` property of the form to `True`.

> When this property is set to true, the form will receive all KeyPress, KeyDown, and KeyUp events.

More information in [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Note [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) says "A control on a form may be programmed to cancel any keystrokes it receives. Since the control never sends these keystrokes to the form, the form will never see them regardless of the setting of KeyPreview."